# c++ opengl vertices with multiple texture coordinates using GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to render a Textured Model, using OpenGL, to keep the graphics RAM low I'm using the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.
Now I want to set multiple Texture Coordinates to one vertex using the element-array-buffer, but sadly I can't find a tutorial or any documentation how do that or if that is even possible.

It would be awesome if someone answers me following questions:
is it even possible to set multiple Texture Coordinates to one vertex?
and if it is possible, where i can find some documentation?
(sorry i haven't included my Code :( )

Comment: It is possible via the use of shaders, using vertex attribs. Are you using shader ? Which version of OGL are you using ?

Comment: yes, I'm using a shader but it's not finished jet so I'm still changing it. I'm using 3.2 at least I enabled it in glew. If I print GL_VERSION I get the number: 7938.

Comment: Then you have to pass your texCoords (or whatever) to your shader using vertex attribs.

Comment: i just noticed that I may haven't described my question properly. I know how to pass the texCoords, but now how do I know which texCoords, I should use for my current triangle? do to the element array I have to pass them all at once or is there a variable to know which triangle I'm currently Rendering.  (sorry if i don't get it. I just started learning OpenGL)

Comment: Vertex attribs are dispatched per vertex, when calling glVertexAttribPointer the 'size' and 'type' parameters define what is an attrib for ONE vertex (ie glVertexAttribPointer(..., 4, GL_FLOAT, ...) will give each vertex ONE vec4 (4 floats) from your data (the n-th vertex will get the n-th vec4), you don't have access to all the attrib array in the vertex shader, only to one element.